# I want to put comma with decimal value in calculator by pressing equal in c#

Tags: c#

I want to put comma with decimal value in calculator by pressing equal in c#.

**Example :** `1234.1234` will be `1,234.1234`.

My code in below - but it is not working :

```
private void TextBoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = TextBox.Text.Replace(",", "");
    long ul;
    if (ulong.TryParse(value, out ul))
    {
        TextBoxCost.TextChanged -= TextBoxCostTextChanged;
        TextBoxCost.Text = string.Format("{0:#,#0}", ul);
        TextBoxCost.SelectionStart = TextBoxCost.Text.Length;
        TextBoxCost.TextChanged += TextBoxCostTextChanged;
    }
}
```

Can anybody help how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you change your number type to double and use double.TryParse:

```
  string value = TextBox.Text.Replace(",", "");
  double dbl;
  if (double.TryParse(value, out dbl))
  {
      TextBoxCost.TextChanged -= TextBoxCostTextChanged;
      TextBoxCost.Text = string.Format("{0:#,#0.0000}", dbl); // or {0:#,#0.####}
      TextBoxCost.SelectionStart = TextBoxCost.Text.Length;
      TextBoxCost.TextChanged += TextBoxCostTextChanged;
  }
```

This is because ulong.TryParse will fail when it finds decimal points. You also used a long as your out parameter for ulong.TryParse, rather than a ulong, which is also not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
string a = (1234.1234).ToString("#,##0.0000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`Convert.ToDecimal(number).ToString("#,##0.00");`